# Between outer and inner classes, their static initializers run order is different when invoking main method inside or outside the outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-initializer

I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    static { //static initializer block
        System.out.print("Foo");
    }
    class Bar {
        static { //static initializer block
            System.out.print("Bar");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { // => This will print "FooBar" to the console
        new Foo().new Bar();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // This will print "BarFoo" to the console
        new Foo().new Bar();
    }
}
```

As the comments say, they will print different result on independent invocation of main methods. Why the placement of main method in this case affect the result printed to the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Foo().new Bar()` is compiled to the following bytecode:

```
NEW Foo$Bar
DUP
NEW Foo
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL Foo.<init> ()V
INVOKESPECIAL Foo$Bar.<init> (LFoo;)V
```

Note that it is `Bar` that is first created (though `Foo`'s constructor is called first). The `new` instruction is what causes a class to be initialised (see [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.new)), *not* the constructor call. The  When a class is initialised, its static initialisers run (see [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)).

Just in case you are not aware, non-static inner classes are implemented by having the constructors take an extra parameter, which serves as the enclosing instance. `new Foo().new Bar()` is basically saying `new Foo.Bar(new Foo())`, but only the former syntax is valid.

I'm not sure if such an output is behaviour *guaranteed* by the spec. It could technically have been compiled in a way such that `NEW Foo` occurs first, but that would require an additional variable, as if you wrote:

```
var f = new Foo();
f.new Bar();
```

So when you put `new Foo().new Bar()` in an unrelated class, `Bar` gets initialised first, and so `Bar` is printed first.

When you put `new Foo().new Bar()` in a static method declared in `Foo`, however, `Foo` will be initialised before any of the `new` instructions, hence `Foo` is printed first. This is because calling a static method in `Foo` causes `Foo` to be initialised.

See all the conditions for a class or interface `T` to be initialised in the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

Note that the first one refers to the execution of the `new` instruction, not the constructor call.